# State propagation from uncertain control input

Tags: kalman-filter, ekf, uncertainty

Consider a nonlinear system $x(k+1)=f(x(k),u(k))$, where $x(k)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the state, $u(k)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is the control input. Here $u(k)$ is normally distributed RV with mean $\mu_u(k)$ and variance $\Sigma_u(k)$. I want to find the distribution of $x(k)$ starting from some deterministic $x(0)$ for some horizon $K$.
Then can the ordinary EKF update equation be used for the prediction in the below way?

\begin{align*}
\mu_x(k+1)&=f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k)),\\
\Sigma_x(k+1)&=\nabla_x f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))\Sigma_x(k)\nabla_x f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))^\top+\nabla_u f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))\Sigma_u(k)\nabla_u f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))^\top
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This approach is commonly used when IMUs are present because they measure the rate of state change with some uncertainty.

Comment: Is there no need to add the term $2\nabla_x f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))\Sigma_{xu}(k)\nabla_u f(\mu_x(k),\mu_u(k))^\top$?

Comment: Usually $\Sigma_{xu}$ is zero. You'll have to include it if it's not.

Comment: It being non zero would mean the random control input is correlated with your state.